# How to trigger list of jenkins jobs sequentially in a loop

Tags: jenkins, groovy, groovyscriptengine

I am new to Groovy DSL, I am getting a list of successful jenkins job names from a script which satisfies my condition which will vary on each execution, EX1: JOB_A,JOB_B.. EX2: JOB_C,JOB_Y...I need to trigger these result list of jobs at the time of execution of the script sequentially in a for loop from Script console using Groovy script. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Do you really need to execute it in the Script console? Most things are a lot easier in a pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a pipeline you can use

```
jobList.each{ jobName ->
    build: jobName
}
```

Comment: I am not executing in a pipeline i am running these through  script console. Can you please  help  me understand your logic.

Comment: If you want to execute a script on a regular basis, it's a lot easier to write a pipeline than using the script console every time

Comment: Ok but how do we trigger  other builds without providing the authentication token?